# locally free sheaf on étale topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of finite rank $d$ on étale topology $X_{\acute{e}t}$, i.e. for every point $x \in X$ there is an étale neighbourhood $U \rightarrow X$ containing $x$ in the image such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a free $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U)$-module of rank $d$. Does it imply that $\mathcal{F}$ is already locally free sheaf in Zariski topology?

Comment: This follows from fpqc descent, and you can find it in almost any book discussing the etale cohomology.

Comment: This is sometimes called "Hilbert's theorem 90", because it is a generalisation thereof (classical H90 is the case where $d = 1$ and $X = \operatorname{Spec} k$). That might help you locate a reference in any text on the étale topology.

Comment: Just to give a concrete reference, this is Proposition 35.8.11 in the Stacks Project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DX). If you'd like to learn more about descent, my favorite exposition is in the book "Neron models" by Bosch, Lutkebohmert, and Raynaud.

Comment: Thank you, I also found theorem 11.4 in Milne's étale cohomology and it looks more accessible.